# Parse string to association

Tags: string-manipulation

Here is a string, which I call `data`:

```
(1)  Turkey   -   Italy         @ Stadio Olimpico, Rome
(2)  Wales    -   Switzerland   @ Olympic Stadium, Baku
```

I can process it as follows:

```
StringReplace[
  "(" ~~ id__ ~~ ")" ~~ Whitespace ~~ Shortest[team1__] ~~ 
    Whitespace ~~ "-" ~~ Whitespace ~~ Shortest[team2__] ~~ 
    Whitespace ~~ "@ " ~~ venue__ :> <|"id" -> ToExpression[id], 
    "team1" -> team1, "team2" -> team2, "venue" -> venue|>] /@ 
 ImportString[data, "Lines"]
```

But the result of each is a `StringExpression`:

```
(* {StringExpression[<|"id" -> 1, "team1" -> "Turkey", 
   "team2" -> "Italy", "venue" -> "Stadio Olimpico, Rome"|>], 
 StringExpression[<|"id" -> 2, "team1" -> "Wales", 
   "team2" -> "Switzerland", "venue" -> "Olympic Stadium, Baku"|>]} *)
```

I can use `Identity@@@` to remove `StringExpression`, but the fact that `StringReplace` gives me such a weird output makes me think that it must not be right tool for the job. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are useful:

```
data = "(1)  Turkey   -   Italy         @ Stadio Olimpico, Rome
(2)  Wales    -   Switzerland   @ Olympic Stadium, Baku"

Association @@@ 
 StringCases[data, 
  RegularExpression[
    "\\(([0-9])\\)\\s+(\\w+)[\\s-]+(\\w+)[\\s@]+(\\S+.+)"] -> 
     {"id" ->"$1", "team1" -> "$2", "team2" -> "$3", "venue" -> "$4"}]
```

> {<|"id" -> "1", "team1" -> "Turkey", "team2" -> "Italy",
> "venue" -> "Stadio Olimpico, Rome"|>, <|"id" -> "2",
> "team1" -> "Wales", "team2" -> "Switzerland",
> "venue" -> "Olympic Stadium, Baku"|>}

Alternatively,

```
StringCases[#, 
    "(" ~~ id__ ~~ ")" ~~ Whitespace ~~ Shortest[team1__] ~~ 
      Whitespace ~~ "-" ~~ Whitespace ~~ Shortest[team2__] ~~ 
      Whitespace ~~ "@ " ~~ venue__
     :> <|"id" -> id, "team1" -> team1, "team2" -> team2, "venue" -> venue|>][[1]] & /@ ImportString[data, "Lines"]
```

> {<|"id" -> "1", "team1" -> "Turkey", "team2" -> "Italy",
> "venue" -> "Stadio Olimpico, Rome"|>, <|"id" -> "2",
> "team1" -> "Wales", "team2" -> "Switzerland",
> "venue" -> "Olympic Stadium, Baku"|>}

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `StringSplit` + `StringTrim`:

```
values = StringTrim /@ StringSplit[ImportString[data, "Lines"], "(" | ")" | "-" | "@"];

keys = {"id", "team1", "team2", "venue"};

AssociationThread[keys, #] & /@ values
```

> ```
> {<|"id" -> "1", "team1" -> "Turkey", "team2" -> "Italy",
>    "venue" -> "Stadio Olimpico, Rome"|>,
>  <|"id" -> "2", "team1" -> "Wales", "team2" -> "Switzerland", 
>    "venue" -> "Olympic Stadium, Baku"|>}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

[`StringReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html) returns a [`String`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/String.html) or [`StringExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html).

If you want to return something else use [`StringCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html).